# Java Utilizing variables in Eclipse after program runs

Tags: java, python, eclipse

So I am a bit new to Java and Eclipse. I am more used to python. Using IDLE in python I am able to run my program from it's file and and then continue to use the variables. For example, if I have all the code written out defining a function, in idle I can just write it there.

```
x = foo()
print x
```

However, in Java it seems like I need to put that in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

This is fine if I already know everything I want to do with a function, but what if I am running a code that took a day to run, and forgot to write the out put to a file. In python, I can just wait for it to finish running and then write it to a file in IDLE. In Java I need to tell it to write it to a file in the main method and then re run it. 
Is it possible to set up Eclipse to work like IDLE where you don't need rerun a program if you want to do new things with the variables already calculated?

I have never used NetBeans, but would this type of thing be easier to do in NetBeans?

Comment: Your main method is incorrect. It should be `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: It sounds like you want a debugger? I am sure there are good ones for Java.

Comment: Not necessarily a debugger. I think it's what Elliott said. I want the freedom to use the variables and methods generated by my program after it runs without needing to have typed in what I want to do with each variable and method before running the program.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a compiled language, python is a scripting language. You could use scala, or jython (or another scripting language) to get the behavior you want. It's also possible to use a [*Scrapbook page*](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-create_scrapbook_page.htm) in eclipse, but that isn't a true [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (which is what you same to be asking for).

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is one that sounds like its a python based environment.  in this case you are storing the variables into your IDE's runtime variable pool.  thats why you can later go and act on a variable you set up.  in eclipse when you run your program you are launching a new instance of java that is disconnected (from variables in the memory heap point of view) from the instance of java that is running eclipse.  once that copy of java that is running your program exits all its memory (including that holding variables) is returned to the system you are running on.